# Swagger.json not getting fed to swagger ui

Tags: java, json, swagger, swagger-ui

Being a greenhorn , I have tried to integrate swagger-core with my rest api following this link -> 
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5

Was facing some issues with setScan function of BeanConfig so downgraded reflections package as can be seen from my maven file below:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.18</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                 <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
         <version>3.13.6</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This was Application startup method:

```
 public void start() throws Exception {
       BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
       beanConfig.setVersion("2.0");
       beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
       beanConfig.setHost("0.0.0.0:8082");
       beanConfig.setBasePath("/test");
       beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.confluent.kafkarest.resources");
       beanConfig.setScan(true);
       beanConfig.setPrettyPrint("true");
       if (server == null) {
         createServer();
       }
    server.start();
  }
```

By this i was able to generate swagger.json at root path. 
Now, I wanted to feed this json to swagger ui , so i added dependancy in maven pom.xml as can be seen above. And modified the code like below:

```
      public void start() throws Exception {
           BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
           beanConfig.setVersion("2.0");
           beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
           beanConfig.setHost("0.0.0.0:8082");
           beanConfig.setBasePath("/test");
           beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.confluent.kafkarest.resources");
           beanConfig.setScan(true);
           beanConfig.setPrettyPrint("true");
           if (server == null) {
             createServer();
           }
        server.setHandler(buildSwaggerUI()); //--> added this method call.
        server.start();
      }

      public static ContextHandler buildSwaggerUI() throws Exception {
        ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
        rh.setResourceBase(KafkaRestApplication.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResource("META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/3.13.6")
            .toURI().toString());
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/swagger");
        context.setHandler(rh);
        return context;
      }
```

After this, I am able to get pretty default swagger ui but now swagger.json has gone. I am not getting swagger.json anymore. I tried to follow this blog:
https://danielflower.github.io/2016/04/01/Swagger-with-embedded-jetty-without-magic.html

I am really struggling to get swagger ui working with swagger json spec. I feel I am missing something silly ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following [this](https://github.com/cunla/embedded-jetty-swagger/blob/master/src/main/java/org/delirium/swagger/app/App.java) link. My working code looked something like this:

```
      public void start() throws Exception {
           BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
           beanConfig.setVersion("2.0");
           beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
           beanConfig.setHost("0.0.0.0:8082");
           beanConfig.setBasePath("/test");
           beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.confluent.kafkarest.resources");
           beanConfig.setScan(true);
           beanConfig.setPrettyPrint("true");
           if (server == null) {
             createServer();
           }
        final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(buildSwaggerUI());
        handlers.addHandler(buildContext());
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
      }

      private static ContextHandler buildContext() {
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().packages(WS_PACKAGE, "io.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
        ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);
        ServletHolder eBrowser = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
        ServletContextHandler eContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        eContext.setContextPath("/");
        eContext.addServlet(eBrowser, "/*");

        return eContext;
      }

      public static ContextHandler buildSwaggerUI() throws Exception {
        ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
        rh.setResourceBase(KafkaRestApplication.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResource("META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/3.13.6")
            .toURI().toString());
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/swagger");
        context.setHandler(rh);
        return context;
      }
```

Comment: This is a useful example thank you. I do have one question though. I have a similar application to yours. I am able to access the swagger.json file on **http://localhost:8080/swagger.json** but I am unable to access the swagger-ui through *http://localhost:8080/swagger*. Throws a HTTP 500 error. Is there something more that need to do?